# For loop inside For

Tags: apex, class, list, account, for

I want to avoid this For loop inside another For... Is there any way for my situation?

```
  public class ManagerAccountTeamMember {
  public static Boolean isFirstTimeBEFORE = true;

  public static void myMethod (List TeamMembers) {

    for( AccountTeamMember accTeamMember: TeamMembers){
        if(accTeamMember.TeamMemberRole == '001'){
           isFirstTimeBEFORE = false;
           accTeamMember.Code__c = '001';
         } 

         if(isFirstTimeBEFORE) {
            isFirstTimeBEFORE = false;

            Map accId_X_TeamMember = new Map();

             for(AccountTeamMember TeamMember : TeamMembers) {
                     accId_X_TeamMember.put(TeamMember.AccountId,TeamMember);
             }
    
             List accounts = [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accId_X_TeamMember.keySet()];

             for(Account account : accounts) {
                 if(acc.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId()) {
                    accId_X_TeamMember.get(account.Id).addError('Msg');
                  }
              }
        }
   }
 }    
}
```

Comment: Your outer loop could be totally removed save the static `isFirstTimeBEFORE` logic, whose intention is unclear. What exactly is this code supposed to do? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.s: The correct is  `Set<String> accId = new Set<String>();`  
 and
 `Map<String,AccountTeamMember> accId_X_TeamMember = new Map<String,AccountTeamMember>();`

What I did:

1. I created a  `Set`   to add the  `AccountIds`  of  `AccountTeamMembers`
2. So I use the method  `contais`  to search the itens of the  `Set`  in the another  `for`  looping

```
public class ManagerAccountTeamMember {
   public static Boolean isFirstTimeBEFORE = true;

   public static void myMethod (List TeamMembers) {
      if(isFirstTimeBEFORE) {
         isFirstTimeBEFORE = false;

         SetString>  accId = new SetString>();
         Map accId_X_TeamMember = new Map();

         for(AccountTeamMember TeamMember : TeamMembers) {
            if(accTeamMember.TeamMemberRole == '001'){
               accTeamMember.Code__c = '001';
                  accId.add(TeamMember.AccountId);  
             }
             accId_X_TeamMember.put(TeamMember.AccountId,TeamMember);
         }
    
         List accounts = [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accId_X_TeamMember.keySet()];

         for(Account account : accounts) {
            if(!accId.contains(account.Id)){
               if(acc.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId()) {
                  accId_X_TeamMember.get(account.Id).addError('Msg');
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }    
}
```